# How Android bluetooth connect to two devices simutaniously?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an APP to connect 2 bluetoothh devices simutaniously.

One is OBD2 device and the other sensor.

I am able to connect each of it but I am not able to connect two at same time.

I already tried using two threads but doesn't really work.

If anyone could give me some hints how to connect two devices simutaniously, I would be appericiated.

Thank you

Comment: How does it not really work? Can you post some code to illustrate the issue?

Comment: I don't think you can use same Bluetooth profile to connect/communicate two different devices at the same time. You may for example use A2DP and FTP with two different devices simultaneously but not only FTP. I may be wrong but that's what my perception is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is really easy. 
All I need to do is to create another bluetooth service object and feed in with another bluetooth address.

Also I feed in with a blooean to determine different deveice data comes in.